# difficulty with my neural network code

Tags: matlab, debugging, neural-network

I have developed my code and I want to post-process my output, but I receive this error message.

```
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Error in mapminmax (line 74)
        if out2.no_change

Error in nm (line 20)
    output1 = mapminmax('reverse', output, Tar)
```

below is the code.

```
% Matlab program for predicting temperature using relative humidity has the
% input
Training_set = xlsread('Traindata.xlsx');
Testing_set = xlsread('Testdata.xlsx');
Input = Training_set(1:701, 2:4);
Target = Training_set(1:701, 1);

%normalise the input and the target
[Inp In] = mapminmax(Input');
[Tar Tr] = mapminmax(Target');

%create a back propagation network
Network = newff(Inp, Tar, [10], {'tansig', 'purelin'}, 'trainlm');

%train the network`enter code here`
Network = train(Network, Inp, Tar)
view(Network)
output = sim(Network, Inp);
error = output - Tar;
output1 = mapminmax('reverse', output, Tar)
```

Comment: show us mapminmax. also, it looks like (though I code be wrong) there's a ' in the line *[Inp In] = mapminmax(Input');*  that's messing things up

Comment: I agree with @Daniel your error points to line 74 of `mapminmax` - what is happening there? And why?

Comment: looking at your error message, you try to call `out2.no_change`. But `out2` is not a [`structure`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) and thus has no [`field`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html#inputarg_field) called `no_change`

Comment: If you are interested in neural networks, you may consider joining the machine-learning site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41738/machine-learning